# Next.js 13 (App directory: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, babeljs

I wanted to add downshift library. When I copied an example of basic usage from [GitHub](https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift/tree/master/src/hooks/useSelect), an error occured.

Versions:
Next.js: 13.2.4
React: 18.2.0

As soon as I understand, it's a kind of babel issue. The code of component that causes the error is just a basic usage example from downshift GitHub (link above).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select component should be client component.

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components

**Add "use client" directive to the downshift select file.**